# Go get from GCP source repositories

Tags: go, go-modules, google-cloud-source-repos

I'm trying to `go get` a repository from GCP Source repositories.
This seems to be very very poorly documented but what I tried to do was running `go get source.developers.google.com/p/[MY-PROJECT]/r/[MY_REPO].git`.

But I got the error:

go: downloading source.developers.google.com/p/[MY-PROJECT]/r/[MY_REPO].git v0.0.0-20210621185528-a62b060bc13d

go get: source.developers.google.com/p/[MY-PROJECT]/r/[MY_REPO].git@v0.0.0-20210621185528-a62b060bc13d: verifying

module: source.developers.google.com/p/[MY-PROJECT]/r/[MY_REPO].git@v0.0.0-20210621185528-a62b060bc13d: reading [https://sum.golang.org/lookup/source.developers.google.com/p/[MY-PROJECT]/r/[MY_REPO].git@v0.0.0-20210621185528-a62b060bc13d](https://sum.golang.org/lookup/source.developers.google.com/p/%5BMY-PROJECT%5D/r/%5BMY_REPO%5D.git@v0.0.0-20210621185528-a62b060bc13d): 410 Gone
server response:
not found: source.developers.google.com/p/[MY-PROJECT]/r/[MY_REPO].git@v0.0.0-20210621185528-a62b060bc13d: invalid version: git fetch -f origin refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/3eb4fda67ba3d1beb54fafd4a7594a34c06a66c44b1ffd91759a1b7362ecfa4d: exit status 128:
fatal: unable to connect to source.developers.google.com:
source.developers.google.com[0: 173.194.200.82]: errno=Connection refused
source.developers.google.com[1: 2607:f8b0:4003:c0d::52]: errno=Connection refused

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding GOPRIVATE=source.developers.google.com. Seems that `go mod` was trying to use a public connection which was being refused by Source.